# How to concat pandas dataframe in columns as shown below

Tags: python, pandas

i would to like know how to concat columns in my dataframe.I have a excel sheet as shown

```
Input   out1    out2    out3    out4    out5
i1  x   o   x   x   o
i2              x   o
i3  x   o   x   x   o
i4  x   o       o   x
```

I would like to how to concat the above columns as shown below

```
Input   out1    out2    out3    out4    out5
i1  i1x i1o i1x i1x i1o
i2              i2x i2o
i3  i3x i3o i2x i3x i3o
i4  i4x i4o     i4o i4x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### empty cells are NaNs

Assuming the empty cells are NaNs, you can select the "out" columns with [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) (or with another method), then [`radd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.radd.html) the Input column:

```
cols = df.filter(like='out').columns
# ['out1', 'out2', 'out3', 'out4', 'out5']

df[cols] = df[cols].radd(df['Input'], axis=0)
```

Output:

```
  Input out1 out2 out3 out4 out5
0    i1  i1x  i1o  i1x  i1x  i1o
1    i2  NaN  NaN  NaN  i2x  i2o
2    i3  i3x  i3o  i3x  i3x  i3o
3    i4  i4x  i4o  NaN  i4o  i4x
```

Reproducible input:

```
from numpy import nan

df = pd.DataFrame({'Input': ['i1', 'i2', 'i3', 'i4'],
                             'out1': ['x', nan, 'x', 'x'],
                             'out2': ['o', nan, 'o', 'o'],
                             'out3': ['x', nan, 'x', nan],
                             'out4': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'o'],
                             'out5': ['o', 'o', 'o', 'x']})
```

##### empty cells are empty strings

If you have empty strings, follow the same logic but [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) the originally empty cells:

```
cols = df.filter(like='out').columns
# ['out1', 'out2', 'out3', 'out4', 'out5']

df[cols] = df[cols].radd(df['Input'], axis=0).mask(df[cols].eq(''), '')
```

Output:

```
  Input out1 out2 out3 out4 out5
0    i1  i1x  i1o  i1x  i1x  i1o
1    i2                 i2x  i2o
2    i3  i3x  i3o  i3x  i3x  i3o
3    i4  i4x  i4o       i4o  i4x
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Input': ['i1', 'i2', 'i3', 'i4'],
                             'out1': ['x', '', 'x', 'x'],
                             'out2': ['o', '', 'o', 'o'],
                             'out3': ['x', '', 'x', ''],
                             'out4': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'o'],
                             'out5': ['o', 'o', 'o', 'x']})
```

Answer (score 0):

**set data**

```
data = {
    "input":["i1","i2","i3"],
    "out1":["x","o","x"],
    "out2":["x","x","x"],
    "out3":["o","o","x"],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
cols = df.columns
df
```

**melt and concat strings**

```
df = df.melt(id_vars="input", value_vars=df.columns[1:])
df["value"] = df["input"] + df["value"]
df
```

**reset index and columns**

```
df = df.pivot(index="input", columns="variable")
df = df.reset_index()
df.columns = cols
df
```